# Receiving file attachments from Zapier to a Laravel webhook

Tags: laravel, zapier, laravel-10

I'm trying to have an email with an attachment forwarded to Zapier which then forwards that to a Laravel webhook.

When it sends it to the webhook, Laravel never can seem to determine that there is actually the file in the payload.

This is the data Zapier is forwarding to the webhook:

```
payload_type:   json
wrap_in_array:  no
unflatten:  yes
url:    https://example.com/webhook
file:   {{123456789__attachment}}
data:
    account:    1234
```

In the Laravel webhook I have this code that checks if a valid file was sent:

```
if (!$request->hasFile('file')) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'No file attached',
        'request' => $request->all(),
    ], 400);
} elseif (!$request->file('file')->isValid()) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Invalid file',
        'request' => $request->all(),
    ], 400);
}
```

This always results in the error `No file attached`.

This is the config for the webhook step in Zapier:
[image]

I've also tried sending the payload raw, but that doesn't work either.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here when I try to check the attached file?

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I got a similar issue.